# Are S3 methods synchronous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can't seem to find the answer to this online anywhere.

I'm using the AWS S3 Ruby gem to call `move_to` on my objects in S3. Immediately after moving, I read the S3 object in its new location. Once in a blue moon, this read will throw a `No Such Key` error -- only once in a while, probably a few times in thousands of runs of this code.

Can anyone confirm that `move_to` is a synchronous call? If it's not synchronous, how do I ensure that the object exists in its new location before reading it?

Comment: The answer may actually depend on your bucket's S3 region and whether the underlying action of `move_to` is actually considered to be creation of a new object by S3 (which I suspect to be true). I'm guessing the bucket is in us-standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS S3 operations are eventually consistent. Data is stored redundantly in several places, and it can take time for every location to be updated. So if your read happens to hit the first place that was updated, you see the effect of the operation right away. If it hits another node, the updates may not have propagated to it yet.